# Pandas Convert Particular columns to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Let's say I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(['Apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'Apple'], columns=['A'])

df4 = pd.DataFrame({'Q':['chair', 'desk', 'monitor', 'chair'], 'R':['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'purple'], 'S': ['english', 'german', 'spanish', 'english']})

df3 = pd.merge(df2, df4, left_index=True, right_index=True)



 df3

        A        Q       R        S
0   Apple    chair     red  english
1  orange     desk    blue   german
2    pear  monitor  yellow  spanish
3   Apple    chair  purple  english
```

What I want to do is create an array that looks like this:

```
df3_array_col_a = ['Apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'Apple']
df3_array_col_b = ['chair', 'desk', 'monitor', 'chair']
```

etc.

Is there a way to do this?

What I tried doing was this:

```
df6 = df3
df6 = df6.columns.get_values()
df6.tolist()
```

But this gives me this:

```
['A', 'Q', 'R', 'S']
```

I then tried doing this:

```
df6 = df6.A.get_values()
```

But this gives me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#54>", line 1, in <module>
    df6 = df6.A.get_values()
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'A'
```

Comment: `df3.A.tolist()`

Comment: Use `df3_array_col_a = df3['A'].tolist()`

Comment: If you post this as the answer, I'll mark it as the solution. Jezrael

Comment: @LunchBox - It is dupe, so rather not.

Comment: okay, sounds good :(